# Unable to understand and obtain the solution to the expected task

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, return-value

I have a player_test.c file and a player.h and a player.c file. This is the error im running, I understand that it has something to deal with return variables and incorrect arguments but I'm not sure where I have it messed up on.

```
L5_Player_Tests.c: In function 'main':
L5_Player_Tests.c:66:16: error: assignment to expression with array type
   66 |         holder = str_Player(&p1, empty_arry) ;
      |                ^
L5_Player_Tests.c:70:40: warning: passing argument 2 of 'show_Player' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   70 |         show_Player("First Player is", holder);
      |                                        ^~~~~~
      |                                        |
      |                                        char *
In file included from L5_Player_Tests.c:45:
player.c:39:35: note: expected 'Player *' but argument is of type 'char *'
   39 | void show_Player(char *s, Player *p)
```

This is the task expectation:

> Create a single Player variable with name Jane and score 67, and display it with:
> (A) function str_Player(), and also its size (sizeof(Player_variable))
> See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf
> int sprintf(char *s, const char *fmt, [arg1, arg2, ... ]) ;
> (B) function show_Player()

This is my player_test.c file.

```
#include <string.h>
#include "player.c"
int main() {
    printf(" " __DATE__ " " __TIME__ "\n") ;
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------\n"
           "1. str_Player() and show_Player()\n");

    Player p1 = {"Jane", 67} ;
    char empty_arry[10];

    char holder[10] ;
    holder = str_Player(&p1, empty_arry) ;

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(holder));

    show_Player("First Player is", holder);

    pause("Pause ... ") ;
}
```

This is my player.c file

```
typedef struct {
    char name[NAME_SIZE] ;
    int  score ;
} Player ;


/* If p != NULL, this creates string s from Player *p; e.g. "Sam 56", and
   returns s; if p == NULL, this returns "NULL"
REF: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf                              */
char *str_Player(Player *p, char s[]) {
   
   if (p != NULL){
      sprintf(s,"%s %d", p->name, p->score);
      return s;
   }
   if (p == NULL){
      return 0;
   }
}
```

This is my player.h file

```
/* If p != NULL, this creates string s from Player *p; e.g. "Sam 56", and
   returns s; if p == NULL, this returns "NULL"
REF: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf                              */
char *str_Player(Player *p, char s[]) ;
```

Comment: About `holder = str_Player(&p1, empty_arry);`. You can't re-assign the array `char holder[10] ;`. It is fixed. Perhaps you can try `char *holder = str_Player(&p1, empty_arry);` instead.

Comment: it still returns the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Well, the compiler is right:**

```
   char holder[10] ;
   holder = str_Player(&p1, empty_arry) ;
```

The compiler complained:

```
    assignment to expression with array type
```

`holder` is `char[10]` a constant. You cannot change a constant.

AND

```
    char holder[10];
    // ...
    show_Player("First Player is", holder);
```

but `show_Player()` is

```
void show_Player(char *s, Player *p)
```

The compiler complained:

```
passing argument 2 of 'show_Player' from incompatible pointer type
expected 'Player *' but argument is of type 'char *'
```

`holder` is `char[10]` and not `Player*`

- the `#include` in `player_text.c` is wrong. You should not include the `.c` file but the `.h` one.
- the struct should be defined in the header not in the `C` file.

### EXAMPLE

#### the `player.h` file

From

```
/* If p != NULL, this creates string s from Player *p; e.g. "Sam 56", and
   returns s; if p == NULL, this returns "NULL"
REF: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf                              */
char *str_Player(Player *p, char s[]) ;
```

You could use

```
#define NAME_SIZE 20
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    int  score;
} Player;

int   show_Player(Player*, const char*);
char* str_Player(Player* p, char s[]);
```

The header is the place where you define the constants, structs and the function prototypes.

#### the `player.c` file

From

```
typedef struct {
    char name[NAME_SIZE] ;
    int  score ;
} Player ;


/* If p != NULL, this creates string s from Player *p; e.g. "Sam 56", and
   returns s; if p == NULL, this returns "NULL"
REF: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf                              */
char *str_Player(Player *p, char s[]) {
   
   if (p != NULL){
      sprintf(s,"%s %d", p->name, p->score);
      return s;
   }
   if (p == NULL){
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Try something like

```
#include "player.h"

int show_Player(Player* pl, const char* msg)
{
    if (pl == NULL) return -1;           // no player
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);  // optional
    printf("%s [%d]\n", pl->name, pl->score);
    return 0;
}

char* str_Player(Player* p, char s[])
{
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;
    sprintf(s, "%s [%d]", p->name, p->score);
    return s;
}
```

that is simpler to read. And note that `player.c` includes `player.h`. This is the way to go.

And no not test for `p != NULL` and then for `p == NULL` in the place. We can expect that one or the other is true.

#### `main.c`

```
#include <string.h>
#include "player.c"
int main() {
    printf(" " __DATE__ " " __TIME__ "\n") ;
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------\n"
           "1. str_Player() and show_Player()\n");

    Player p1 = {"Jane", 67} ;
    char empty_arry[10];

    char holder[10] ;
    holder = str_Player(&p1, empty_arry) ;

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(holder));

    show_Player("First Player is", holder);

    pause("Pause ... ") ;
}
```

Is rather confusing. Try

```
#include "player.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf( __DATE__ " " __TIME__ "\n\
--------------------------------------------------------------\n\
    1. str_Player() and show_Player():\n");

    Player p1 = {"Jane", 67}; // a player

    char  place_holder[10+NAME_SIZE];
    char* pStr = place_holder;

    str_Player(&p1, pStr);
    printf("\
    sizeof(place_holder) = %zu\n\
    Using str_Player(): %s\n",
        sizeof(place_holder), pStr);
    show_Player(&p1, "    Using show_player(): First Player is ");
    return 0;
}
```

- using a single printf() is way faster and makes easier to see what will be printed
- use a `char*` to take the address of a sufficiently large area to pass to the string.
- do not use `pause()` or `system()`: you are using `C`. You can write anything in `C`. And if your IDE can not stop at the end of the program change the IDE not the program.

#### output

```
Nov  3 2022 XX:YY:ZZ
--------------------------------------------------------------
    1. str_Player() and show_Player():
    sizeof(place_holder) = 30
    Using str_Player(): Jane [67]
    Using show_player(): First Player is Jane [67]
```

Comment: Whenever I am needed to create a new Player using str_player(), is it a must to create a place_holder every time?

Comment: It is still your code. `str_player()` *does not create a new `Player`*. It just returns a string with the contents if a `Player`. This area must exist so I called the string _place_holder_ Your logic will say if it can be reused or not.